# Convert words to number in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have an API connected to my Sheets where I receive data in words instead of numbers.
Example, Ratings data is recieved as "Five" instead of numeric "5".
How do I convert the recieved data into numeric values?
I have tried =value() and it doesn't seem to be working.

Answer (score 1):

1- Try this for one single number

```
function toNum(txt){
  var num = ["zero", "one", "two", "three", "four", "five","six", "seven", "eight", "nine"]
  return num.indexOf(txt.toLowerCase())
}
```

[image]

2- You can also use a standalone formula (following Gangula's idea)

```
=MATCH(A1,{"zero"; "one"; "two"; "three"; "four"; "five";"six"; "seven"; "eight"; "nine"},0)-1
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Using [Mike's solution below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70693277/6908282) you can create a custom function in [Google Apps Scripts](https://www.google.com/script/start/). But you can also achieve this by using `VLOOKUP`

---

You can simply create a sheet which has all the possible ratings in Text and numeric values. Then you can use `VLOOKUP` to convert the data from actual sheet to numbers

Refer to the [following sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1_dwDWcGOaD36n2WnDsm1UFGTfTvNwPdWNEfgdDx3RfM/edit?usp=sharing).

```
=ArrayFormula(VLOOKUP(A4:A14,'Text to Num'!A1:B9,2,FALSE))
```

**Note**: `ArrayFormula` is used so that you don't have to copy paste formula in multiple cells.

[image: Text to Number]